# Disable the cache?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I've looked around the web and found you can clear the cache via:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

I am looking for a solution where you can turn off the cache in a dev environment. I do not want to run the above cmd everytime.

```
 return Cache::remember('my-key', 60, function() {
        //get page
    });
```

So above I check the cache, this occurs throughout my app, is there a simple way to disable it in a dev environment?

Comment: What I currently use as a workaround is define a `cacheTime` config, and set it to `0` in dev, and the desired amount in production. I use this configuration as the second argument everywhere.

Comment: I tried setting it to 0, but this seems to make the cache persist 'forever'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your cache driver to **array** in **.env** file for your **DEV** environment. This way cache will be wiped out at the end of every request, but you'll be able to use **Cache** facade.

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```