# Laravel File system reboot

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Is there a way to restart the Laravel file system after uploading modified .css and php files?

The change is not getting triggered in my case.

Thanks and Best

Comment: no such reboot is required, if your not seeing the changes, open an incognito window and see if you see them there, if so, its your cache.

Comment: If its just cache, do this in Chrome: **CTRL + SHIFT + R**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009137/disable-the-cache)

Answer (score 0):

**CTRL+F5**  *forces the Cache to clear. hence generating the correct result.*

Look at this: [Clearing Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all cache Artisan command  via these command.

`php artisan cache:clear`

And to clear route cache:

`php artisan route:clear`

To clear view cache:

`php artisan view:clear`